# How to change background of imageView on mouse over inside the Horizontal Scroll view

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

I have a horizontal scroll view. Inside this there is a LinearLayout which contains Images how can I change the background of Image when Mouse over of that image.

Comment: Ummmm... on mouse over?   This is an Android app, right?

Comment: @Anil which device supports mouse ??

Comment: @Indiandroid I have a Android media box and I want to do this.

Comment: got it man i have watched this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gbBDdSdJ1E @Anil

Comment: @Indiandroid You can suggest me for onHover event also.

Comment: @Anil  i can't because never worked on it before.

Comment: Inside what ? What are you indicating in your question ?

Comment: @GrIsHu Check question description.

Answer (score 0):

Use a selector for the background of your images like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_hovered="true" android:drawable="@color/hovered_color"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>

</selector>
```

Note: only works on API 14 and up

Comment: Can you elaborate it.

Comment: @Indiandroid Check http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0.html "Input Framework" Android add support for cursors in ICS

Comment: Please can you give me an example.

Comment: Check here for an selector example: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/

Comment: Thanks... but I think that it is not wokring when it is inside the Horizontal Scroll Bar. Now I am trying to do this.